# Unable to install ImageMagick on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew

I can't install ImageMagick on my Mac:

```
brew install ImageMagick
==> Downloading http://www.imagemagick.org/download/releases/ImageMagick-6.9.2-4.tar.xz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading http://ftp.nluug.nl/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.2-4.tar.xz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "imagemagick"
Download failed: http://ftp.nluug.nl/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.9.2-4.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After uninstalling brew and installing brew again this work fine thanks.

here is the command to install brew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an outdated Homebrew. Run `brew update` then try again; ImageMagick is known for changing their URLs very frequently and break the old ones; so if you haven’t updated `brew` for a long time you might get build failures.